# Linker Error undefined reference to vtable

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, linker-errors, vtable

I seem to be having an issue with a wxWidgets project I'm working on. I keep getting a vtable linker error for a class that doesnt involve any virtual functions. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this issue, since in my understanding there shouldnt be a vtable for a class that doesnt use virtual functions. Most similar topics I've seen occur when someone forgets the define the deconstructor, but I'm pretty sure the deconstructor was correctly defined.  the errors can be seen below.

```
||=== Hike Planner GUI, Debug ===|
obj\Debug\GUIFrame.o||In function `PlanWindow':|
E:\Projects\Hike Planner GUI\GUIFrame.cpp|76|undefined reference to `vtable for              PlanWindow'|
E:\Projects\Hike Planner GUI\GUIFrame.cpp|76|undefined reference to `vtable for PlanWindow'|
obj\Debug\GUIFrame.o||In function `~PlanWindow':|
E:\Projects\Hike Planner GUI\GUIFrame.cpp|81|undefined reference to `vtable for PlanWindow'|
E:\Projects\Hike Planner GUI\GUIFrame.cpp|81|undefined reference to `vtable for PlanWindow'|
E:\Projects\Hike Planner GUI\GUIFrame.cpp|81|undefined reference to `vtable for PlanWindow'|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

segment from GUIFrame.h

```
class PlanWindow : public wxWindow
{
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()

    public:
        PlanWindow(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id);

        ~PlanWindow();

        void GetLocationList(int RetCode);

        wxListBox *PlanList;
};
```

Segment from GUIFrame.cpp:

```
PlanWindow::PlanWindow(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id) : wxWindow(parent,id) 
{

}

PlanWindow::~PlanWindow()
{

}

void PlanWindow::GetLocationList(int RetCode)
{
    if(RetCode == DEST)
    {

    }
    else if(RetCode == TH)
    {

    }
    else if(RetCode == FREE)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

any help at all would be great. the errors occur at the contructor and destructor definitions.

Comment: There is already a correct answer but I'd just like to mention that you ''always'' have virtual functions in your `wxWindow`-derived class, e.g. its dtor is virtual because it is virtual in `wxWindow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to *implement* the declared event table using `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE`/`END_EVENT_TABLE` in your `cpp` file. An example;

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(PlanWindow, wxWindow)
//  EVT_SIZE (PlanWindow::OnSize)       // Example size handler
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Comment: wow. i knew it was something dumb i was doing. didnt expect it to be that dumb. thanks so much. =]